# Fitting table in HTML

Tags: php, html, html-table

I'm trying to design a webpage where it simply shows info from a database using PHP.
I almost solve all of my problem but it's the first time I'm using HTML and I am having trouble finding a solution for my problem.

The code I have so far is:

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','XXXX','XXXX');
mysql_select_db('cardata_laptimer');

echo "<table>";
echo "<table border = 1>";

$query = "SELECT * from tempos GROUP BY piloto";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$query = "SELECT * from tempos WHERE piloto = '" . $row['piloto'] . "' ORDER BY tempo";
$resultado = mysql_query($query);

echo "<td>" . $row['piloto'] . "</td></tr>";

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
{
    echo "<td>" . $rows['tempo'] . "</td><td>" . $rows['data'] . "</td></tr>";
}
}
```

The output I'm getting can be seen in www.cardata.pt

1st problem: How to I make the "piloto" (for example AA) occupy the space of 2 cells?

2nd problem: I want the table to show "pilotos" side by side and the info for each one (tempo and data) down the piloto name.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I might be wrong, but you don't seem to be starting the `<tr>` anywhere, you only seem to close them? And why are you making two tables inside each other?

Comment: You are correct. I didnt start any <tr>, didn't knew I had to :P

Comment: I'd recommend that you find a tutorial on how to write html.

Answer (score 1):

To occupy the space of 2 cells add : colspan="2"
here is my edit of your code :

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','XXXX','XXXX');
mysql_select_db('cardata_laptimer');

echo '<table border="0"><tr>';

$query = "SELECT * from tempos GROUP BY piloto";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<td><table border="1"><tr>';
$query = "SELECT * from tempos WHERE piloto = '" . $row['piloto'] . "' ORDER BY tempo";
$resultado = mysql_query($query);

echo '<td colspan="2">' . $row['piloto'] . "</td></tr><tr>";

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
{
    echo "<td>" . $rows['tempo'] . "</td><td>" . $rows['data'] . "</td>";
}
echo '</tr></table></td>';
}

echo '</tr></table>';
?>
```

Comment: Tyvm. Just like I was reading in here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_tables.htm . From what I've seen (for my 2nd problem) they always define the rows first and then change line. That was not I was attempting to do with my code.